# Is using SharePoint lists a good interim solution for MS Access?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access-2016

I have several 2016 MS Access database applications that are well designed and implemented over a shared network.  Currently there are minimal issues and the databases are utilized by about 100+ people. All users have front ends that are automatically updated whenever the master copy, also on the shared network, changes versions. These front ends took 2-3 years to develop and were mindful of the company's limitations at the time.

The company is considering completely reverting to Microsoft Office 365, but I have been told that they plan to hold on to MS Access as long as possible.  That said, I'd rather take a proactive approach.  I have done some tests with Microsoft SharePoint and found that as long as the linked list follows the requirements necessary within SharePoint, like the 'Title Field', autonum ID field, I can keep all of the complex queries as long as they stay in my front ends. This is ideal as an interim solution, because it would buy time to completely upgrade my front end to something more current.

Is there a better approach to preserve the front end design without having to start again from scratch, and if not, what medium would be best if I have access to Visual Studio and SQL Server?

Comment: _reverting to Microsoft Office 365_ ..? _Microsoft 365_ includes _Microsoft Access_, so what is your concern?

Comment: Yes, but not FlankSpeed, a DOD repository that doesn’t include MS Access, however I just heard about Dataverse with the Access connector so that’s really good news.